# How to find mathematical sum of positive and negative numbers in a single cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, sum

I have a column which has positive and negative numbers. I want to find the sum of them. All the values are in Number datatype. 
When I use auto sum, I get 0.00 as my result.

[Column Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOvN5.jpg)

Also, the values in the column were populated from another columns (like =B2-C2)
However, if I copy and paste the values alone in another column and sum it up, I get the desired result

Comment: It sounds like you have numbers formatted as text. Or they all add up to 0. But a screenshot of some sample data would help.

Comment: Are the numbers naturally left or right aligned in the cell (i.e. you haven't forced them to left/right alignment).  If they're left aligned then they are being treated as text.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with BigBen, it sounds like your data is in text format. Even though you change the format on the "Home" tab to "Number", it still might be read by Excel as text.

To quickly change all text "numbers" to real numbers, select the range of numbers and use the "Text to columns" feature under the "Data" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that your data is being interpreted as numbers. 
For instance, use in E2 "=2*D2". You should get the corresponding number. 
Do the same for all your sources cells.
(Given that you mention that these are results from calculations, I expect these to be actually numbers).

If any of the results gives you trouble, you already have the source of your problem.

If all the cells contain numbers, try using in F2 "=SUM(D2:D2)" and expanding the range one cell at a time. 
You should be able to identify the source of the problem.

You may help others help you by making your workbook available somewhere online.

You don't need [autosum](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-autosum-to-sum-numbers-543941e7-e783-44ef-8317-7d1bb85fe706), just `SUM` (which is anyway the function setup by autosum).

Comment: I tried both and see that they are numbers. When I do a sum on column D and E, I get the result to be 0.00

Comment: @kacy - I suggest, 1) make your workbook available for downloading, 2) don't use autosum.

Comment: Is there any other alternative other than autosum? 
if I copy and paste the values alone in another column and sum it up, I get the desired result